# Typescript: "i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile."

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, iis-express

My Typescript build is failing but I don't know why. "i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile." is the error message. It's cryptic with funny characters. How do I get the build error to show properly?

I'm using IIS Express, ASP.NET Core and Angular in this project.

Here's a more detailed log

```
Zoolander.UI> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
Zoolander.UI>       Date: 2018-09-19T00:32:16.011Z
Zoolander.UI> Hash: 8e2f800b0afe50fe39a9
Zoolander.UI> Time: 4989ms
Zoolander.UI> chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.93 kB [initial] [rendered]
Zoolander.UI> chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 682 bytes [initial] [rendered]
Zoolander.UI> chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
Zoolander.UI> chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 201 kB [initial] [rendered]
Zoolander.UI> chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 325 kB [initial] [rendered]
Zoolander.UI> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
Zoolander.UI> 
Zoolander.UI> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Zoolander.UI>       Request finished in 9279.8092ms 404 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. For a more verbose error message:

- Open a command line
- Go to your app directory (e.g. ClientApp)
- Build the Angular app: ng build

Comment: This worked for me. Instead of something cryptic I got...  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.html'

Comment: So there is no way to get any sort of proper errors from webpack directly? Just... wow.